# How to get the first and last elements from dates along with other elements in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

In MongoDB I want to get a list of events between a start and an end date.

```js
db.events.find({
  date: {
    $gte: new Date("2021-02-15T01:04:00.697Z"),
    $lte: new Date("2021-02-22T01:04:00.697Z"),
  },
})
```

Every events have a `user_id` property.

For each unique `user_id`, I want to get the last previous and first following events outside the start and end dates.

Right now I'm doing it by performing an aggregate by getting the first date greater than the end date (and same thing with the start date).

```js
db.events.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      date: {
        $lt: new Date("2021-02-15T01:04:00.697Z"),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user_id",
      previous: { $last: "$_id" },
    },
  },
])
```

```js
db.events.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      date: {
        $gt: new Date("2021-02-22T01:04:00.697Z"),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user_id",
      next: { $first: "$_id" },
    },
  },
])
```

Then with the `previous` and `next` properties I fetch the related events.

I was wondering if there is a way to do everything in a single aggregate call? Or at least a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in one query by using `$facet`.

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {
        $facet:{
            'previous': [
                {
                    $match: {
                        date: {
                            $lt: new Date("2021-02-15T01:04:00.697Z"),
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$user_id",
                        previous: { $last: "$_id" },
                    },
                },
            ],
            'next': [
                {
                    $match: {
                        date: {
                            $gt: new Date("2021-02-22T01:04:00.697Z"),
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$user_id",
                        next: { $first: "$_id" },
                    },
                },
            ]
        }
    }
])
```